# How to forbid usbdisk in centos?

Tags: linux, centos, security

In win, we can use group policy, but my company use centos6.5 destop as os. My boss want to avoid information leak.
Then, is there a method to forbid usbdisk in centos?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist usb-storage
```

and restart the system (or unload the module if it is already loaded with `modprobe -r usb_storage`).

Comment: so easy?90% staff in our company is professional coder.I worry about they  can revise this conf even they have no root password.

Comment: @jackson883 It requires root access to undo this. This prevents the drivers from loading, so it is impossible to use a USB storage device.

Comment: And you could enforce it with something like puppet - then if they manage to change it the change will be reverted to the desired state on the next puppet run. Then you can monitor the interval between puppet runs if you think they just disable puppet

Comment: Also, if they manage to undo this, they'll have complete control over the system anyway and nothing you do except making the USB ports physically unusable (e.g. fill with hot glue) will protect you.